# php soap request on cpanel

Tags: php, soap, cpanel

I have develop a process using soap request. It is running fine on local machine with windows xp. But when I have upload on cpanel server it is not going to execute properly. I have notice it stopped processing after this line `$client->loadWSDL();`. $cleint object going to create fine. If some one know what problem it may have.

Thanks in advance.

```
require_once('lib/nusoap.php');
require_once('config.php');


$params = "<CreateUsersRequest xmlns='http://www.abc-online.com/services/api/1.0/'>
              <Credentials>
                <EmailAddress>$emailaddress</EmailAddress>
                <Password>$password</Password>
                <CustomerID>$customerID</CustomerID>
              </Credentials>
              <Emails>
                <string>$newEmail</string>
              </Emails>
              <AutoGeneratePassword>false</AutoGeneratePassword>
              <Password>$newPassword</Password>
              <SendLoginEmail>true</SendLoginEmail>
              <PersonalComment>$comment</PersonalComment>
            </CreateUsersRequest>";
        //
        $client = new soapclient($accountURL.'/services/api/1.0/soap_server.asmx?wsdl',array('encoding'=>'UTF-8'));


    ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0"); 
    //$err = $client->getError();
    //echo $err;

    $client->setUseCurl(0);
    $client->loadWSDL();
    $userCreated = $client->call('CreateUsers',$params);

    //find out if it worked
    $userCreatedStatus = $userCreated['Success'];
```

Comment: Please, post your loadWSDL() logic. Maybe it is usign some kind of method not allowed in php config from your hosting

Comment: "function loadWSDL() {
  $this->debug('instantiating wsdl class with doc: '.$this->wsdlFile);
  $this->wsdl = new wsdl('',$this->proxyhost,$this->proxyport,$this->proxyusername,$this->proxypassword,$this->timeout,$this->response_timeout,$this->curl_options,$this->use_curl);
  $this->wsdl->setCredentials($this->username, $this->password, $this->authtype, $this->certRequest);
  $this->wsdl->fetchWSDL($this->wsdlFile);
  $this->checkWSDL();
 }
"

Comment: You are using cURL, sometimes hosting servers doesn't have that function allowed, please do a phpinfo() and tell me if you have cURL enabled in your server or not

Comment: I have check it. cURL is enabled

Comment: thats weird, do you have some error message? or nothing happens? try to put your code inside try catch and maybe look for something

Comment: Yes getting no error and this is the main problem. let me try with try catch

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13887/discussion-between-nbhatti2001-and-oscar-jara)

Comment: I found this error now. Function ("loadWSDL") is not a valid method for this service